# how to finde date of inserted record in sql server 2008

Tags: get

I need to create new field  and  insert into field date of record inserted  table Previously exist have date inserted

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use something like this

```
INSERT INTO [YourTableName] ([SomeDateColumn]) VALUES (GETDATE())
```

Comment: this is get date now but i wanted  to update one field by  date of record  inserted